# How can I get this code to update a record in zoho

Tags: php, curl, zoho

I've tried changing things around and all I every get is 'false'.
(I was getting errors until I fixed a problem with the strlen) - now just false.
(I have no problem getting records to view)
I have tried this as PUT and PATCH...

```
    $user = 'someuser';

    $base_url = 'https://creator.zoho.com';
    $url = "$base_url/api/v2/$user/client-list-2/report/Contact";

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    
    $criteria = "ID=98989231239213"; // id is not a string in zoho
    $fields = json_encode(
        [   "criteria" => $criteria,
            "data" => ["RBT_ID" => "$rbt_id"]   / RBT_ID is a string in zoho
        ]
    );
    $fields_length = strlen($fields);

    $header = array('Content-Type: application/json',
                    "Content-Length: $fields_length",
                    "Authorization: Zoho-oauthtoken $creds->access_token");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```